# Flutter is not Installing on my Window 10 Laptop

Tags: flutter

I am trying to install in my laptop but it fail to install. When i run command in "command prompt. It shows this error that i have show you in Screenshot. When i run 2 commands that shown in Screenshot nothing happend. It shows error again and again. I have also installed window 10 again in my laptop this issue is not resolving.

Anyone can tell me the solution how can i fix this issue?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0w4X.jpg)